# Cordova get stream from camera without opening it

Tags: android, cordova, camera, android-camera

Im currently trying to develop an android application with cordova. I want to get the stream from the camera. On Windows I achieved that like this:

```
if (!(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia)) {
    alert("NO CAMERA SUPPORTED");
    return;
} 

var video = document.querySelector("#capture-video video");

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then((stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
});
```

which is working fine. However, on Android I always get a NonReadableError when trying to alert the stream ID with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).then(stream => alert(stream.id);` and the video stays blank. My config.xml is looking like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="'utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </edit-config>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
            <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
        </config-file>
        <icon src="www/img/logo2.png"/>
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <preference name="android-manifest/application/activity/@android:windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I also tried different cordova plugins like cordova-media-capture and others but they all opened the default camera which is not what i want. Does anybody have an idea how I could achieve it to let the user take a photo but not using the default camera application?